# Not passing params to action with form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]I can't figure out why my form is not passing params to the registration controller. I have a registration form that doubles as a login form using jquery and javascript. My second form (the last one) is supposed to send over registration info to the registration controller. Unfortunatly I keep getting wrong number of arguments (0 for 1). I'm not sure how I'm not passing the information in, any help is appreciated.

new.html.erb

```
<div id="imageDisplay"></div>

<div class="login-switch">
  <div id="login-div" class="button button-outline button-calm switches active-button">
    LOG IN
  </div>
  <div id="signup-div" class="button button-outline button-calm switches">
    SIGN UP
  </div>
</div>

<%= form_for(@user, url: sessions_path, html: {id: "sign-in-form"}) do |f| %>
  <div class="list list-inset">

    <label id="sign-up-input" class="item item-input">
      <%= f.email_field :username, autofocus: true %>
    </label>
    <label id="sign-up-input" class="item item-input">
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </label>

    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "button button-block button-calm" %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<%= form_for(@user, url: registrations_path, html: {id: "sign-up-form"}) do |f| %>

  <div class="list list-inset">
    <div id="part-1">
      <!-- part one of sign up -->
      <label id="sign-up-input" class="item item-input">
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "E-mail" %>
      </label>

      <label id="sign-up-input" class="item item-input">
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password" %>
      </label>

      <label id="sign-up-input" class="item item-input">
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off",placeholder: "Confirm password" %>
      </label>

      <div id="slide-part-2" class="button button-block button-calm">Next</div>

    </div>

    <div id="part-2">
      <!-- part two of sign up -->
        <%= f.file_field :avatar, id: "fileInput"%>

      <label id="sign-up-input" class="item item-input">
        <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, placeholder: "username" %>
      </label>

    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "button button-block button-calm" %>

    </div>
<% end %>

  </div>

</div>
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
[![enter image description here][1]][1] def new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.create(sign_up_params)
        if @user.save
            log_in @user
            flash[:success] = "We Made it!"
        else
            flash[:error] = @user.errors
        end
    end

    private 

    def sign_up_params
        params.require.(:user).permit(:email, :username, :avatar, :password, :password_confirmation, :trump)
    end

end
```

Comment: try to remove `.` -> `require.(:user)` => `require(:user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says `wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)`, it's because you didn't pass any argument in the `require` method, you added a `.` before the opening parenthesis for the argument, you need to remove it, because Ruby is executing `(:user)` as a method but its not. Fix this error by correcting the typo as **dp7** mentioned in his answer

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :username, :avatar, :password, :password_confirmation, :trump)
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: this is the result of no sleep while trying to code. such a silly mistake, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `.` after `params.require`:

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :username, :avatar, :password, :password_confirmation, :trump)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like that :

```
 def sign_up_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :username, :avatar, :password, :password_confirmation, :trump)
 end
```